# Rails 3.2.7 auto reloading lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I've tried most of the solutions such as `require_dependency`, adding `autoload` in `application.rb`, and enabling the `lib` folders but still no dice.

Here's how my application is set up:

I have in `lib/index_tank_searcher.rb`:

```
  class IndexTankSearcher < Spree::Core::Search::Base
    def method
    end
  end
```

And I have `Spree::Config.searcher_class = IndexTankSearcher` in `config/intializers/spree.rb`.

Any ideas on how to make sure that `index_tank_searcher.rb` auto reloads without restarting the server each time it changes?

Comment: I'm having a hard time answering, because I don't know what your question is/what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Code in an initializer is only run once when the application loads. Setting the searcher_class to IndexTankSearcher in the initializer is might be preventing it from reloading.

Comment: Ah! You might be right Beerlington. Any way to get around it since it seems like I need to set this class before the app loads?

Comment: Apologies @ksol, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reloading classes doesn't mutate existing classes. Classes to be unloaded are unassigned from their constant and a fresh copy is assigned. This is easily verifiable in the console

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > User.object_id
 => 70274894338560 
1.9.3p194 :003 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :004 > User.object_id
 => 70274935456220
```

However `Spree::Config.searcher_class` is still set to the original `IndexTankSearcher` class.

You could add a [to_prepare](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch) callback that will be called on each request in development, but only once (on startup) in production

Comment: This was spot on! I just had to add `Spree::Config.searcher_class = IndexTankSearch if Rails.env.development?` in the `to_prepare` callback in `application.rb` and it worked like a charm. Thank you Frederick! I appreciate it!